# Proximity Search example Lucene.Net

Tags: c#, .net, lucene.net

I want to make a [Proximity Search](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches) with Lucene.Net. I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/343002/searching-phrases-in-lucene) where it looks like that was the answer for him, but no code was suplied. The Java documentation says to use the ~ character with the number of words in between, but I don't see where this character would go in the code. Anyone can give me an example of a Proximity Search using Lucene.Net?

**Edit:**

What I have so far:

```
IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(this.Directory, true);

string[] fieldList = new string[] { "Name", "Description" };

List<BooleanClause.Occur> occurs = new List<BooleanClause.Occur>();
foreach (string field in fieldList)
{
     occurs.Add(BooleanClause.Occur.SHOULD);
}


Query searchQuery = MultiFieldQueryParser.Parse(this.LuceneVersion, query, fieldList, occurs.ToArray(), this.Analyzer);
```

If I try to add the "~" with any number on the MultiFieldQueryParser it errors out saying that for a FuzzySearch the values should be between 0.0 and 1.0, but I want a Proximity Search 3 words of separation Ex. "my search"~3

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, the ~ character goes directly in the text of the query (as shown in the docs you link to).

Comment: @Odrade please see the modifications I did to the question. I tried that but the parser thinks I'm trying to make a FuzzySearch.

Comment: Sorry,  I don't have any actual expertise on Lucene .NET.  I just thought you might be missing something obvious in the docs.  It doesn't look that way, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The tilde means either a [fuzzy search](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Fuzzy%20Searches) if you apply it on a single term, or a [proximity search](http://lucene.apache.org/java/2_3_2/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches) if you apply it on a phrase. The error you're receiving sounds like you're applying it on a single term (term~10) instead of using a phrase ("term term"~10).

> To do a proximity search use the tilde, "~", symbol at the end of **a Phrase**.

Answer (score 1):

The only differences between Lucene.NET and classic java lucene of the same version should be internal, not external -- operational goal is to have a very compatible project, especially on the input (queries) and output (index files) side. So it should work however it works for java lucene. If it don't, it is a bug.

Comment: Don't you have some code example on how I could achieve a Proximity Search? I haven't used Java Lucene nor Lucene.Nat before and the documentation available is not that great, at least for Lucene.Net